# OpenIAB dont work Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

i include OpenIAB plugin in my Android application in unity3D, but when i test my app on device, purchase window isnt called. Where problem??

```
void Start() {

    OpenIAB.mapSku (SKU, OpenIAB_Android.STORE_GOOGLE, "no_ads");
    var options = new OnePF.Options();
    options.checkInventory = false;
    options.verifyMode = OptionsVerifyMode.VERIFY_EVERYTHING;
    options.storeKeys.Add(OpenIAB_Android.STORE_GOOGLE, "My key");
    OpenIAB.init(options);


}
void OnGUI(){

    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (100, 100, 100, 100), "Push me")) {

        OpenIAB.purchaseProduct(SKU);
        GUI.TextArea(new Rect(200,200,150,150),"Its work!!!");

    }

}

private void OnPurchaseSucceded(Purchase purchase)
{


    if (purchase.Sku == SKU)
        GUI.TextArea(new Rect(150,150,150,150),"Good job!");


}
```

Answer (score 0):

GUI functions only work inside **OnGUI()** call. And  **GUI.TextArea(new Rect(200,200,150,150),"Its work!!!");** just probably blinks too fast.